# Do these objects keep their properties if we apply an homeomorphism on them: $(u_n)$ convergent, $(u_n)$ bounded, and $(u_n)$ Cauchy.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

> If we apply a homeomorphism on these objects, do they keep their properties. Let $f: (X, d_{X})\rightarrow (Y, d_{Y})$. And let:
>   a)$(u_n)$ is a convergent sequence of $(X, d_X)$
>   b)$(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence of $(X,d_X)$
>   c)$(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of $(X,d_X)$

For $a)$, I didn't have any problems, as by the continuity of $f$ we have $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim u_n}=l \iff \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim f(u_n)}=f(l) $. So the answer is yes, the property is kept.

Now, for $b)$, I am rather unsure. I have a hard time finding a counter example, and don't know how to prove that the property are kept.

Finally, for $c)$, I think it will depend on whether $X,Y$ are complete.
If they are both complete, then I can use the fact that then $u_n$ converges to some $l \in X$ and :
$$d_Y(f(u_n), f(u_m)) \leq d_Y(f(u_n), f(l)) + d_Y(f(l),f(u_m))$$
Would it be true if for example one is complete and another isn't? Or if both aren't complete?

**EDIT 1:**
So based on the hint given my Max, if I put $(X, d_X)= (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot |)$ and then take $(Y, d_Y)(\mathbb{R}, \frac{|\cdot|}{1 + |\cdot|})$, then I am not sure what the homeomorphism would be equal to? Would $f(x)=x$ be enough?  The sequence ould definitely be bounded on $(\mathbb{R}, \frac{|\cdot|}{1 + |\cdot|} )$, and I think a Cauchy sequence on the first metric would be a Cauchy sequence on the second metric space.

Comment: We can have a homeomorphism of topological spaces that doesn’t exactly preserve the metric (and a metric appears in the definition of *bounded* and *Cauchy* sequences).  Think perhaps in terms of how one might alter the metric on a topological space without changing the topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X = Y = (0,\infty)$, both endowed with the absolute value as metric.  Let $f: X \to Y$ be given by $f(x)=1/x$.  It's easy to see that $f$ is a homoemorphism.

Then consider the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset x$ given by $x_n = 1/n$.  Then $f(x_n) = n$.  This example handles the latter two of your three questions.

Comment: Well, it handles (b) and (c), but not (a). However, as the OP has realized, (a) is almost trivial.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, what's the topology induced by $\frac{d}{1+d}$ ? Or $\min (1,d)$ ?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the hint. I made an edit concerning it, can you check it out? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Your edit is on the right track but you've written something weird when you said "$(\mathbb{R}, \frac{d}{1+d})$ is actually equal to $([0,1],\frac{d}{1+d})$". Maybe you meant $B(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I just realised it makes no sense, not sure what I ment. I will edit it out! And thank you!

Comment: Ok great ! Well the homeomorphism you give is the right one : we say that the distances $d$ and $\frac{d}{1+d}$ are *topologically equivalent*. And you can also show that Cauchy sequences for $d$ are the same as Cauchy sequences for $\frac{d}{1+d}$. (It might be easier to do it with $\min (1,d)$)

Comment: So it works well in this case, but would it work in any $(X, d_X), (Y, d_Y)$ that are homeomorphic?

Comment: What do you mean ? The question is "is it true that in any case, any bounded (resp. Cauchy) sequence is sent by any homeomorphism to another bounded (resp. Cauchy) sequence ?". If the answer is no, all you need to do is find a counterexample. For instance the property for bounded sequences is *true* if $X$ is compact, but that doesn't matter since you were asked (in this case) for a counterexample